# Common Sorting Algorithms

Tags: c#, algorithm, .net, sorting

Here I've prepared my solutions for the following algorithms, and was curious if there were a way to optimize any of them. Any input is welcome and appreciated!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace algotest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void InsertionSort(int[] arr)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; ++i)
            {
                int temp = arr[i];
                bool sorted = false;

                for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0 && !sorted;)
                {
                    if (temp < arr[j])
                    {
                        arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                        --j;
                        arr[j + 1] = temp;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sorted = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static void BubbleSort(int[] arr)
        {
            int temp = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length - 1; ++j)
                {
                    if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
                    {
                        temp = arr[j + 1];
                        arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static void SelectionSort(int[] arr)
        {
            int temp, min;

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; ++i)
            {
                min = i;

                for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; ++j)
                {
                    if (arr[j] < arr[min])
                    {
                        min = j;
                    }
                }

                temp = arr[min];
                arr[min] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
            }
        }

        static void Merge(int[] arr, int left, int pivot, int right)
        {
            int[] temp = new int[25];
            int index = left;
            int leftBound = pivot - 1;
            int length = right - left + 1;

            while (left <= leftBound && pivot <= right)
            {
                if (arr[left] <= arr[pivot])
                {
                    temp[index++] = arr[left++];
                }
                else
                {
                    temp[index++] = arr[pivot++];
                }
            }

            while (left <= leftBound)
            {
                temp[index++] = arr[left++];
            }

            while (pivot <= right)
            {
                temp[index++] = arr[pivot++];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                arr[right] = temp[right];
                right--;
            }
        }

        static void MergeSort(int[] arr, int left, int right)
        {
            if (right > left)
            {
                int pivot = (right + left) / 2;
                MergeSort(arr, left, pivot);
                MergeSort(arr, pivot + 1, right);
                Merge(arr, left, pivot + 1, right);
            }
        }

        static void QuickSort(int[] arr, int left, int right)
        {
            int i = left, j = right;
            int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

            while (i <= j)
            {
                while (arr[i].CompareTo(pivot) < 0)
                {
                    ++i;
                }

                while (arr[j].CompareTo(pivot) > 0)
                {
                    --j;
                }

                if (i <= j)
                {
                    int temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;

                    ++i;
                    --j;
                }
            }

            if (left < j)
            {
                QuickSort(arr, left, j);
            }

            if (i < right)
            {
                QuickSort(arr, i, right);
            }
        }

        static void Heapify(int[] arr, int i, int n)
        {
            try
            {
                int temp = arr[i];
                int j = 2 * i;

                while (j <= n)
                {
                    if (j < n && arr[j] < arr[j + 1])
                    {
                        j++;
                    }

                    if (temp >= arr[j])
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    arr[j / 2] = arr[j];
                    j *= 2;
                }

                arr[j / 2] = temp;
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException err)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Array Out of Bounds ", err);
            }
        }

        static void HeapSort(int[] arr)
        {
            for (int i = arr.Length / 2; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                Heapify(arr, i, arr.Length - 1);
            }

            for (int i = arr.Length - 2; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                int temp = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = arr[0];
                arr[0] = temp;

                Heapify(arr, 0, i);
            }
        }

        static void CountingSort(int[] arr)
        {
            int[] count = new int[arr.Max() + 1];

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
            {
                ++count[arr[i]];
            }

            int j = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < count.Length; ++i)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < count[i]; ++k)
                {
                    arr[j++] = i;
                }
            }
        }

        static void RadixSort(int[] arr)
        {
            int i, j;
            int[] temp = new int[arr.Length];

            for (int shift = 31; shift > -1; --shift)
            {
                j = 0;

                for (i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
                {
                    bool move = (arr[i] << shift) >= 0;

                    if (shift == 0 ? !move : move)
                    {
                        arr[i - j] = arr[i];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp[j++] = arr[i];
                    }
                }

                Array.Copy(temp, 0, arr, arr.Length - j, j);
            }
        }

        static void BucketSort(int[] arr)
        {
            // bucket size key:
            // array 1-99 ; 10 buckets
            // arrat 100-199 ; 20 buckets
            // etc.
            // TODO: Implement logic to determine bucket size?

            int numOfBuckets = 10;
            List<int> result = new List<int>();
            List<int>[] buckets = new List<int>[numOfBuckets];

            for (int i = 0; i < numOfBuckets; ++i)
            {
                buckets[i] = new List<int>();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
            {
                int index = arr[i] / numOfBuckets;
                buckets[index].Add(arr[i]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < numOfBuckets; ++i)
            {
                int[] temp = buckets[i].ToArray();
                InsertionSort(arr);
                result.AddRange(temp);
            }

            arr = result.ToArray();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please select an algorithm: ");
            Console.WriteLine("I : InsertionSort O(n^2)");
            Console.WriteLine("B : BubbleSort O(n^2)");
            Console.WriteLine("S : SelectionSort O(n^2)");
            Console.WriteLine("M : MergeSort O(nlgn)");
            Console.WriteLine("Q : QuickSort O(nlgn)");
            Console.WriteLine("H : HeapSort O(nlgn)");
            Console.WriteLine("C : CountingSort O(n)");
            Console.WriteLine("R : RadixSort O(n)");
            Console.WriteLine("U : BucketSort O(n)");

            string algorithm = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

            Console.WriteLine("How many elements?");

            int numOfElements = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] arr = new int[numOfElements];
            Random rand = new Random();

            Console.WriteLine("Generating random data...");

            for (int i = 0; i < numOfElements; ++i)
            {
                arr[i] = rand.Next(100);
            }

            switch (algorithm)
            {
                case "I":
                    InsertionSort(arr);
                    break;
                case "B":
                    BubbleSort(arr);
                    break;
                case "S":
                    SelectionSort(arr);
                    break;
                case "M":
                    MergeSort(arr, 0, arr.Length - 1);
                    break;
                case "Q":
                    QuickSort(arr, 0, arr.Length - 1);
                    break;
                case "H":
                    HeapSort(arr);
                    break;
                case "C":
                    CountingSort(arr);
                    break;
                case "R":
                    RadixSort(arr);
                    break;
                case "U":
                    BucketSort(arr);
                    break;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define `optimize`(goal?). Have ordered items at both ends with insertion sort to almost half the number of assignments (first step towards [Library_sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_sort)). Select *min* and *max* concurrently in selection sort, comparing only the lesser of each pair of input items to *min*, the greater to *max* to save one fourth on comparisons. (Next step is to keep pairs ordered to avoid the next quarter: first step to [Heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort).) Annoyingly effective: "bubbling up" candidates. Iterate on quicksort's larger partition.

Comment: (I expected "the optimistic approach to insertion into a heap" to be commented in at least one answer - didn't see that. Improvement: take the pessimistic/realistic approach: just *assume* the child of higher priority to have priority over the *new item*, and only start comparing the latter once the "highest priority path to a leaf" is known.)

Comment: That does not look like a proper bubble sort to me.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: @greybeard That looks like it needs to be an answer! :P

Comment: @Paparazzi Use the program for debugging the algorithms; I assure you it works.

Comment: Works and proper are not the same

Comment: @Paparazzi Then what would you way the algorithm is then?

Comment: Wait a minute. Have you been revising code after getting comments on that code? Why?

Comment: @Mast No, I have only changed Bubble Sort to make it fundamentally that algorithm and be worthy of review. It just required fixing a few variables anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Insertion sort

You don't need the flag variable `sorted`.
Instead of `sorted = true`, you can simply `break` out of the loop.

Many times flag variables can be avoided,
and result in simpler, more readable solutions.
Always look suspiciously at flag variables.

#### Merge sort

The number 25 in `int[] temp = new int[25]` looks arbitrary. Why is it 25?

Note that this may lead to integer overflow,
a common pitfall in merge sort implementations:

> ```
> int pivot = (right + left) / 2;
> ```

The fix is simple enough:

```
int pivot = left + (right - left) / 2;
```

#### Counting sort

The implementation allocates an array of size `arr.Max() + 1` as storage.
It would be good to also take into account `arr.Min()`,
to avoid allocating much more space than necessary.

Furthermore,
the current implementation will crash if the input contains negative numbers.
That's another reason to consider `arr.Min()` too.

Answer (score 1):

### Insertion sort

You appear to be writing the moving element repeatedly, which isn't needed, and as mentioned there is a `sorted` flag you don't need, so you can break out of the loop to place the moving element.

```
    static void InsertionSort(int[] arr)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; ++i)
        {
            int temp = arr[i];
            int j = i - 1;

            while (j >= 0)
            {
                if (temp >= arr[j])   break; // found insertion point

                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                --j;
            }
            arr[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
```

### Bubble sort

Normally bubble sort refers to swapping adjacent elements. It can be optimized by tracking the last swap.

```
    static void BubbleSort(int[] arr)
    {
        int endPt = arr.Length - 1;
        while (endPt > 0)
        {
            int lastSwap = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < endPt; ++j)
            {
                if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
                {
                    int temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                    arr[j+1] = temp;
                    lastSwap = j;
                }
            }
            endPt = lastSwap;
        }
    }
```

### Selection sort

No issues, although you have variables declared a little further from their point of use than in the previous routines.

*... I might look at some more later.*

Comment: I think you meant for the `arr[j + 1] = temp;` to be in the for-loop. Also, for your Insertion sort critique, I get the following when I run my solution: https://i.imgur.com/fMtMEq5.png and this when I run yours: https://i.imgur.com/fO1O3f2.png

Comment: Yes, I was trying too hard for minimal changes, apologies - the `j` variable should persist for the update subsequent to the loop.

Comment: @T145 note that your edit was overwritten by the edit I was making at the same time, which was not the same.